# How do I get the value of the param "to" <Link to="{/xxxxx}" /> on "onClick" function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

How do I get "about", I mean the value of "to=" at onClick?
I've been trying to chase the event details, no luck so far.

I'm using react-router v3, I could update to v4 if needed.

```
onClick(event){
    let _to = event.??
}

<Link onClick={this.onClick} to={'/about'}>about</Link>
```

Comment: it will not work, because `Link` will get converted in **anchor tag**, so if you want to access the `route` name then, pass that value in onclick event: `onClick={() => this.onClick('about')}` then `onClick(route){console.log(route)}`

Comment: Have you tried `let _to = event.target.getAttribute("to");` ?

Comment: `event.target.getAttribute('href')` does the trick